# Ubuntu server starting in read only due to issues with sda1

Tags: boot, server, partitioning

I have an Ubuntu server running in Virtual Box (Bitnami build). After restarting the server the VM failed to restart properly. After asking on the Bitnami forum a nice fellow informed me that there was a problem with the /dev/sda1 partition and it may need to be unmounted/remounted. After googling for hours and trying various commands such as umount /dev/sda1 both using the LiveCD and Read-Only monde on the Server.

Any advice or guidence on how to do this/fix the server would be appreciated!

I have attached an image capture of the Ubuntu Server startup.

[Screen capture of Ubuntu Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5DkJ.jpg)

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Update: I ran a Partition check using Gpart using the LiveCD and it seems to have fixed the startup issue

Comment: Ideally, if you discover the answer to your own question you should [write up a good one](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) here so others with the same issue can benefit from your experience. If you do so, drop me a comment and if you do a good job I'll upvote it, adding to your [reputation here.](http://askubuntu.com/help/reputation)

Answer (score 0):

Posting my fix for anyone who has this issue in the future.

1. Download Live CD iso
2. Open GParted
3. Right click -> Unmount (may not need this step, my partition wouldn't mount to   begin with)
4. Right click -> Check
5. Edit Run -> Run Queue
6. Reboot to main OS